# Cannot run oozie 4.3.0 on apache hadoop 2.7.3

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie, hadoop2

I did all the setup for oozie 4.3.0 on Apache hadoop single node cluster, when tried running any standard example workflow.xml that comes with oozie, it is throwing below error.

> WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[data01.teg.io] USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000000-161215143751620-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000000-161215143751620-oozie-hado-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.]

I looked at the parameter "mapreduce.framework.name" and it is set to yarn everywhere in all config files. I checked Sharelib is created properly and can see when queried with shareliblist command, i dont see where exactly the problem is. Tried every solution came up in google and could not solve it even after struggling for 2 days with it.

I can start and stop oozie daemon with out any problem.

Any insights are greatly helpful.

Comment: Could you provide your job.properties and some more information about your environment..how is it managed? Thanks.

Comment: I'm able to figure it out, just added the solution below, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Unlike the prior versions of Oozie before 4.x.x, 4.3.0 does not generate hadoop-libs.jar file when we run the build command.

In the beginning, i copied jar files only from my hadoop's 
/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common to oozie's libext folder. After i copied jar files from all the below paths to oozie's libext folder, i was able to successfully setup the Oozie.

`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar`
`/srv/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar`